# How to load AttachProvider (attach.dll) dynamically

Tags: java, dll

I'm using `com.sun.tools.attach` from jdk's `tools.jar` and it need an specified `java.library.path` env pointing to `attach.dll` at startup to properly instatiate provider such as `WindowsAttachProvider`. For some reasons I need to dynamic loading one of bundled `attach.dll`. I'm try to use some like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path bin = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),"bin").toAbsolutePath();
    switch (System.getProperty("os.arch")) {
        case "amd64":
            bin = bin.resolve("win64");
            break;
        default:
            bin = bin.resolve("win32");
    }
    // Dynamic setting of java.library.path only seems not sufficient
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + File.pathSeparator + bin.toString());
    // So I try to manual loading attach.dll. This is not sufficient too.
    System.load(bin.resolve("attach.dll").toString());
    // I'm using com.sun.tools.attach in my app
    new myApp();
}
```

If I run this out of jdk (in normall jre) it's report to me:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider:
Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException:
no providers installed
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(...
```

How to install attach provider without specifying `-Djava.library.path` to point `attach.dll` at startup?

Comment: Did you try printing (or debugging) the paths you are forming to see if they are what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I'm printing it before and after and they are what I expect. It seems like an attach api use this env on startup only.

Comment: You can't change java.library.path programatically by setting the system property. There are hacks using reflection. But you probably want to find another solution.

Comment: So, how to use `attach.dll` pointed from java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API you are using is using [loadLibrary(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29). It seems you cannot successfully pre-empt (cause it to succeed) this by invoking the more explicit [load(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) first.

So you must to specify the path in `java.library.path`.

That System property is set once early in JVM lifecycle and is not modifiable by standard means.

So the conventional solution will be to pass an appropriate `java.library.path` when you launch the JVM.

Alternatively, you could look into the hacks to change this property after JVM startup using reflection. I have not tried any of these.

For example, see [here](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/):

```
System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "/path/to/libs" );

Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

BTW, I would recommend pre-pending your custom path to the existing path, rather than replacing it.

Comment: It's sufficient explanation of env problem, but I'm waiting for attach-api-level workaround. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'm look into it and source of openjdk's attach. So, attach-api-level workaround is impossible regards to above. Changing sys path by reflection works and I must use it now, but I'm afraid can I trust this method in portability across Win/Mac/Lin.