# Dynamic library loading with pre and post check using ServiceLoader

Tags: java, dll, serviceloader

This question is next step in solving of [attach library dynamic loading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134159/how-to-load-attachprovider-attach-dll-dynamically). I have some like this:

```
public static void loadAttachProvider(String binPath) throws Exception {
    /*
     * If AttachProvider is already available now then propably we are in JDK
     * or path to attach.dll was specified as java.library.path on startup
     */
    if (isAttachProviderAvailable()) return;

    /*
     * In normall-use code I have generated binPath appropriate to platform (VM)
     * family and bitness (e.g. win32 or win64)
     */
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", binPath);

    // Reload library path hack
    Field sys = ClassLoader.class.getDeclared("sys_paths");
    sys.setAccessible(true);
    sys.set(null, null);

    // Here I want to be sure that AttachProvider is available
    //System.loadLibrary("attach"); <- I'm try this too, but it's not suffiecient
    if (!isAttachProviderAvailable()) {
        throw new IOException("AttachProvider not available");
    }
}
```

Checking for AttachProvider availability looks like:

```
public static boolean isAttachProviderAvailable() {
    // This line is a substance of AttachProvider.providers() method
    ServiceLoader<AttachProvider> providers = ServiceLoader.load(AttachProvider.class, AttachProvider.class.getClassLoader());
    try {
        for (Iterator<AttachProvider> it = providers.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            /*
             * In normall-use code the "windows" constant is replaced
             * by something like platform-specific PLATFORM_FAMILY
             */
            if (it.next().type().equals("windows")) return true;
        }
    } catch (ServiceConfigurationError ex) {}
    return false;
}
```

If you run this with JDK's private JRE then all will be ok, because JDK has `attach.dll` in default library path.

### Problem

This work great only if I remove first `isAttachProviderAvailable` occurence, because if I try to instantiate `AttachProvider` before it is available then I can't instantiate it later when `attach.dll` is loaded. `ServiceLoader` doesn't refresh according to new library path. How to solve this? How to check `AttachProvider` availability without instantiating or how to refresh `ServiceLoader`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with first attach-check replaced with something like this:

```
try {
    System.loadLibrary("attach");
    if (isAttachProviderAvailable()) return;
    throw new IOException("AttachProvider not available");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ex) {
   /*
    * dll can't be loaded, so we need to specify special binpath
    * and reload library path as post above
    */
}
```

However I'm waiting for better solution.